# Smalltalk: Assigning to a Variable Without Declaring a Variable in GNU Smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

In Smalltalk, the GNU version 3.2.5, I do not get any errors when I do not declare a variable like so:

```
v := Array new: 10.
```

as opposed to:

```
| v |
v := 5.
```

But I was under the impression that there should be an error when I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a common thing in Workspaces (playground in Pharo). For code in the (class) browser the compiler is more strict (at least in Squeak/Pharo)

Comment: This answer is also true in GNU Smalltalk.